# Python to open ADODB recordset and add new record

Tags: python, adodb, recordset

in my wxPython app which I am developing I have written a method which will add a new record into an access database (.accdb). I have procured this code from online search however am not able to make it work.  Below is the code:-

```
def Allocate_sub(self, event):
    pth = os.getcwd()
    myDb = pth + '\\myAccessDB.accdb'
    DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
    PWD = 'pw'
    # connect to db
    con = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
    con.Open('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s' % (myDb))
    cDataset = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
    #cDataset.Open("Allocated_Subs", con, 3, 3, 1)
    cDataset.Open("Allocated_Subs", con, 3, 3, 1)
    cDataset.AddNew()
    cDataset.Fields.Item("Subject").Value = "abc"
    cDataset.Fields.Item("UniqueKey").Value = "xyzabc"
    cDataset.Update()
    cDataset.close()
    con.close()
```

However whenever I trigger this code by clicking the button to which I have Bind it I get error saying:-

Can anyone please help me resolve this or let me know of a different way to open a recordset using ADODB and then add a new record into it.

Many thanks.

Regards,
Premanshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the solution, posting here just in case someone refers to it...
it's a small correction in line

```
cDataset.Open("Allocated_Subs", con, 3, 3, 1)
```

it should be:-

```
cDataset.Open("Allocated_Subs", con, 1, 3)
```

Regards,
Premanshu