# Opening 13mb file in openPyXl uses 1.2 gb of memory

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file that is 20x50000. It is around 13mb in size. However calling this line alone: `openpyxl.load_workbook(FILENAME, read_only=True)` takes up over a gigabyte of RAM. This is causing issues in my environment. Any idea what might be causing this? I read from another poster that he had a similar issue and it was a misformatted cell but he hasn't posted for a year now so I doubt I'll see how he fixed it. What could cause this? Let me know if any extra information is needed.

Comment: XLSX file? It's compressed. You can decompress it with 7Zip or rename to .ZIP and then unzip it. How large is the result?

Comment: @ThomasWeller uncompressed it is 100 mb

Comment: Is this on Windows? Perhaps you can make a direct data connection -- no formatting -- using `win32com` and AODB (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263563/python-to-open-adodb-recordset-and-add-new-record)), or [`adodbapi`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/aad84fb376912de7cb0bab673e21f9f372eddb11/adodbapi/adodbapi.py).

Comment: @ZevSpitz so there's no way to fix this within OpenPyXL? It's strange that such a relatively small file is causing such huge memory leaks.

Comment: I would not call it a leak. I have wriiten a JSON Viewer and opening a file uses 7-8 times as much memory as the file on disk. Consider that the uncompressed file, it's already 800 MB. 1. GB is not that far away

Comment: @ThomasWeller true, but the developers do seem to indicate that a file like that shouldn't be breaking the program. Whatever, guess I'll switch to another library

Comment: Can you share the Excel file? Or create a similar one with the same effect that you can share?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Unfortunately the file has PII. I'll look into creating one but finding a new library might legitimately be easier at this point